# ExtJS viewConfig plugin treeviewdragdrop throws error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of null

Tags: plugins, extjs, drag-and-drop, tree

Here is my extended `Ext.tree.Panel`:

```
Ext.define('WP.view.portlet.Tree', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.portlettree',


    store: 'Portlets',
    rootVisible: false,
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'
        }
    }
});
```

When the page is loaded an error is thrown from the `PluginManager.js` file, line 58:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of null`

The examples from Sencha use the same configuration, so I'm not sure what I'm missing that is causing this error. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The error was caused by my referencing only the core `ext-debug.js`. I updated to include `ext-all-debug.js` and the error is resolved. I will mark as answered once I am allowed (low reputation).

Comment: It worked for me too. Thanks Brian Wendt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by my referencing only the core ext-debug.js. I updated my HTML file to include ext-all-debug.js and the error is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to fix this would be to require the plugin in your project.

In this case Ext.tree.plugin.TreeViewDragDrop.

For example:

```
Ext.application({

requires: [
    'Ext.chart.Chart',
    'Ext.chart.series.Line',
    'Ext.chart.series.Column',
    'Ext.chart.axis.Numeric',
    'Ext.chart.axis.Category',
    'Ext.layout.container.Border',
    'Ext.tree.plugin.TreeViewDragDrop'
], 
...
```